# Conversion of core database to realm database in iOS apps using swift

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, realm

I am supposed to convert the Core database of an existing app to the Realm database for much faster querying. During the creation of a model in the realm database, adding an optional int property throws some syntax error. How can I convert an optional property of the core database to realm. Attaching the sample property for reference:

```
        @NSManaged public var chData: [UInt8]?
```

The above-given property is of the Core database. How can I have a corresponding property for realm database?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're asking how to define an optional Int property on a realm object?

```
class MyObject: Object {
    let chDataOpt = RealmOptional<Int>()  //an optional Int
    @objc dynamic var chData = 0       //a non optional Int
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.This is the same way,I too have followed.But RealmOptional doesn't support unsigned integers.Also how can I introduce an array of chDataOpt.Because in my question, chData is declared as an array of type UInt8.So how can I do the same in realm?